# Ошибка при импорте ключа GPG в ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, gpg

```
root@50e29e4059a8:~# gpg --keyserver hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv E2D8289C0A9D2C28A3320B62D2AAFD5D9088F1A2
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
```

Ubuntu запущен в Докер контейнере

Comment: Адрес hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net не существует

Comment: https://sks-keyservers.net/  Update 2021-06-21: Due to even more GDPR takedown requests, the DNS records for the pool will no longer be provided at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

то ли проблемы какие-то у [серверов криптографических ключей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9), то ли перегружены спам-запросами.

пробуйте другие серверы и/или пулы серверов.

после многих неудачных попыток мне вот удалось один раз скачать этот ваш ключ `E2D8289C0A9D2C28A3320B62D2AAFD5D9088F1A2` с сервера `pgp.key-server.io`. если надоест искать рабочий сервер, можете из файла импортировать:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=Y0+A
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```